# Unexpected behaviour of TypeScript array

Tags: typescript

Given a typescript array, I would expect it to limit my options to only adding elements of the value type with an integer index. But this is not really the case and I cannot find a good reason why.

```
var test: string[] = [];
// OK as expected
test[1] = "42";

// Error as expected
test[1] = 42;

// Error as expected
test.test = 42;

// Unexpected OK, why? 
test['1'] = 42;
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20test%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20OK%20as%20expected%0Atest%5B1%5D%20%3D%20%2242%22%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Error%20as%20expected%0Atest%5B1%5D%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Error%20as%20expected%0Atest.test%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Unexpected%20OK%2C%20why%3F%20%0Atest%5B'1'%5D%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%0A

Does anyone know why it is like this?

Comment: Seems, any object has ['some_string'] getter and setter, and Array is object too. But why it is ok for numbers and strings too? http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src='use%20strict'%3B%0Avar%20test%3A%20number%20%3D%201%3B%0Atest%5B'x%20d'%5D%20%3D%201%3B

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way the TypeScript is designed. You are allowed to access any object by string indexers and by default it assumes the type `any`. This is for convinience of porting over existing code.

For stuff that is defined a string indexing leads to valid type checking, consider:

```
var test: string[] = []; 

// Ok 
test['push']('123');
// Error
test['push'](123);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because at JavaScript:

```
var a = [];
a[1] = 123;
a['1'] = 456;
alert(a[1]); // 456
```

**Update 1.**

Possibly TypeScript compiler could not trace that at square brackets there are not a integer (because of only compile-time checks and no runtime overhead)?

For example, how to check a situation at a compile time?

```
var idx = getSomething();
var arr: string[] = [];
arr[idx] = 'Abcdef';
```

**Update 2.**

First, square brackets is not only used for accessing array items, so it is possible to has a attribute with such name.

Second, there is possible a difficult situation to trace.

Example.

```
var idx = {}
idx.toString = (): number => { return 2; };

var arr:number[] = [10, 11, 12, 13];
alert(arr[idx]); // 12
```

It is dynamically correct, but statically... Yes or no?

So, i dont have an answer to your question, but i think that it is just a difficult situation for compiler and it just pass here.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. I would expect TypeScript to error when I do things that do not agree with the type (even if the compiled js is correct js). But in this case typescript seems fine with me using the array as an object. It's not due to using a number in string format either, because if I replace '1' with 'foo' it's still OK. I also understand that all of this is valid JS, that is not the issue, the issue is why the typescript compiler accepts this.

Comment: This is still not the case, because even if idx is any, and compiler accepts this, I am assigning a number to it, which is also in violation with the type.

Comment: As you say - dynamic correct static who knows. I am leaning on that this is a compromise, that for some situations you need to be able to access stuff through bracket operator even for arrays with a specified type. But it's not really documented clearly and is very counter intuitive. I am still hoping someone with more in depth knowledge can give a clear answer why this is OK in ts.